# Removing Whole Numbers from an Alphanumeric String

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble finding a way to remove floating integers from a cell without removing numbers attached to the end of my string. Could I get some help as to how to approach this issue?

For example, in the image attached, instead of:
`john123 456 hamilton`, I want:
`john123 hamilton`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using regular expressions. You will match on the data you want to remove, then replace this data with an empty string.

Since you didn't provide any code, all I can do you for is provide you with a function that you can implement into your own project. This function can be used in VBA or as a worksheet function, such as `=ReplaceFloatingIntegers(A1)`.

> ***You will need to add a reference*** to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` by going to <kbd>Tools</kbd>, <kbd>References</kbd> in the VBE menu.

```
Function ReplaceFloatingIntegers(Byval inputString As String) As String

    With New RegExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "(\b\d+\b\s?)"
        If .Test(inputString) Then
            ReplaceFloatingIntegers = .Replace(inputString, "")
        Else
            ReplaceFloatingIntegers = inputString
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

### Breaking down the pattern

- `( ... )` This is a capturing group. Anything captured in this group will be able to be replaced with the `.Replace()` function.
- `\b` This is a word boundary. We use this because we want to test from the edge to edge of any 'words' (which includes words that contain only digits in our case).
- `\d+\b` This will match any digit (`\d`), one to unlimited `+` times, to the next word boundary`\b`
- `\s?` will match a single whitespace character, but it's optional `?` if this character exists

You can look at this personalized [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/n8ALN6/1) page to see how this matches your data. Anything matched here is replaced with an empty string.